# Google Map API integration with wordpress showing 403 access forbidden

Tags: php, wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Map API from 2 years in my wordpress site, and now when I updated wordpress with few plugins my page of map was showing blank.

I just saw console and there was error 403 access forbidden, but I was surprised that I called URL in script tag like this:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY&callback=initMap"
async defer></script>
```

And when I saw in console there was showing that i am trying to access URL:

```
 <script src="https://www.example.com/?url=https:&D&Dmaps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY&callback=initMap"
async defer></script>
```

something like this (above) URL.

Why wordpress converting my script src to its own structure with its URL and then add google api url encoded as a URL query string.

Comment: Did you add the script tag in a template file? a post? a page?

Comment: Yes I added, even hardcode example for static map is not showing